# How do I negate a filter query by block join in Solr?

Tags: solr

Let's say I have a simple set of nested documents (I'm using the same syntax that Yonik does on his [Solr Nested Documents page](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/)):

```
{
    id: 1,
    parent: true,
    _childDocuments_: [
        {
            parent: false,
            condition: true
        },
        {
            parent: false,
            condition: false
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    parent: true,
    _childDocuments_: [
        {
            parent: false,
            condition: false
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    parent: true,
    _childDocuments_: [
        {
            parent: false,
            condition: true
        }
    ]
}
```

This filter query returns all parent documents which have children with `condition:true`:

```
fq={!parent which=parent:true}(+parent:false AND +condition:true) /* returns 1, 3 */
```

This filter query returns all parent documents which have at least one child that doesn't have `condition:false`:

```
fq={!parent which=parent:true}(+parent:false AND -condition:false) /* returns 1, 3 */
```

How do I make a filter query that returns all parent documents which has zero children that has `condition:false`, i.e. only returns document 3?

```
fq=-{!parent which=parent:true}(+parent:false AND +condition:false) /* throws org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
fq=-_query_:"{!parent which=parent:true}(+parent:false AND +condition:false)"
```

I'm keeping this question open in case anybody has any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's answer returns all documents, except for those parent documents who do not have the condition:false.

That is to say, it returns children of docs 1 and 2 along with entire document 3.

```
q=-_query_:"{parent which=parent:true}condition:false"&fq={!parent which=parent:true}condition:*
```

> The fq in above query will further filter the results (who have no
>   parents for child with condition:false) to give you just the parents
>   without children with condition:false.